# How to print the for /L output in a horizontal direction in batchfile?

Tags: batch-file

I wonder if there is a way to output this generated sequence in a horizontal direction in a batch script?
this is the code:

```
    for /L %%a in (1,1,5) do (
        echo %%a
    )
```

-- outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

i want it like:

```
12345
```

Comment: don't use `Echo` if you dont want a newline. use instead `<nul set /p "=%%a"`

Comment: wow. genius! than you @T3RR0R. but can i store it in a variable?

Comment: can't find a way to put it in a variable, because i want it to put in my choice command.

the choice should be like

choice /c (12345 or variable) /n /m "Select printer "

Comment: i figured it out with this line. i put it in a temporary file. then use a for /f again to read what's inside..thank you very much @T3RR0R

<nul set /p "=%%a" >> temp.tmp

Comment: `SET /a options=0&for /L %%e in (1,1,5) do set /a options=10*options+%%e` - but it will only work for options 1..9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you want to store the output in a variable:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var="
for /L %%a in (1,1,5) do (
        set "var=!var!%%a"
)
echo Result="!var!"
```

Inside a code block you should use delayed expansion to access variables

Comment: this is also a helpful solution..thank you @jeb
i just remove the qoutes as i dont need them in my choice command

choice /c !var! /n /m "Select printer "